# How can i tell the PATCH Method which field i want to update

Tags: sql, sqlite, go

I'm working on a simple REST API and I'm having troubles with the `PATCH` method. I don't know how can i tell the method and the query which fields i want to update(for example which fields are passed as JSON) in the database. Here is what i have so far.

```
func PatchServer(c echo.Context) error {
    patchedServer := new(structs.Server)
    requestID := c.Param("id")
    if err := c.Bind(patchedServer); err != nil {
        return err
    }
        sql := "UPDATE servers SET server_name = CASE WHEN ? IS NOT NULL THEN ? END WHERE id = ?"
        stmt, err := db.Get().Prepare(sql)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err2 := stmt.Exec(patchedServer.Name, patchedServer.Name, requestID)
    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }
    fmt.Println(patchedServer.ID, patchedServer.Name, patchedServer.Components)
    fmt.Println("Requested id: ", requestID)
    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, "Patched!")
    }
```

Comment: You could first `SELECT` the server record from the db using the `requestID`, then bind that existing server with `c.Bind` which will update only those fields that are provided in the json. With that you can now use a simple `UPDATE` query where you set all the columns, those that weren't changed by `c.Bind` will just be set to their old value and those that were changed will be set to the new value.

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you i clearly understand what are you trying to say. I will need some time tho because i don't quite have the code in my head yet.